# Yii2 Routing rules conflicts with each other

Tags: php, routes, yii2

I have the following 2 rules:

```
'blog/<action>' => 'blog/default/<action>',
'blog/<slug:[0-9a-zA-Z\-.]+>' => 'blog/default/view',
```

Also I have the following actions:

```
public function actionCheckSlug($slug) {

}

public function actionCreate() {

}

public function actionView($slug) {
    return $this->render("view");
}
```

When I try to access this URL for example (action URL):

```
/blog/check-slug?slug=test
```

It's working without any problems but when I try to access this URL for example (Slug URL):

```
/blog/test-test-test
```

I will get an error:

```
yii\base\InvalidRouteException: Unable to resolve the request: blog/default/test-test-test
```

Because the fist rules is being parsed instead of the second one.
I tried to reverse them for example but it didn't work (always one is not working), also tried others scenarios but no success

Any idea how to make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest first of all not using the same url convention for both actions

```
'blog/<action>' => 'blog/default/<action>',
'blog/<slug:[0-9a-zA-Z\-.]+>' => 'blog/default/view',
```

could easily become

```
'blog/<action>' => 'blog/default/<action>',
'post/<slug:[0-9a-zA-Z\-.]+>' => 'blog/default/view',
```

or use `'blog/page-<slug:[0-9a-zA-Z\-.]+>'`, `blog/post/` .. or really just any convention that doesn't clash with your existing structure

---

if that's not something just you wanna do, or cant? in your app, you can just use the slug to check for existing app structure.

```
public function view($slug){
    $model = $this->findBySlug($slug);
    return $this->render('view', ['model' => $model]);
}

private function findBySlug($slug){
    if ($this->hasMethod('action' . Inflector::classify($slug)) 
        // this should prevent recursion
        && $slug != $this->action->id){
        $this->runAction($slug);
        return null;
    }
    return Post::find()->where(['slug' => $slug])
}
```

**note**: this is just an example of how to (*or how not to?*). don't run my bad, untested code in any production environment